# Can Google Cloud Build recurse through directories of artifacts?

Tags: google-cloud-build

My workspace looks like this:

```
|
|--> web-app
     |
     |--> src
     |--> build
          |
          |--> fonts
          |--> static
```

My `cloudbuild.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "steps" : [
    {
...
    },
    ],
    "artifacts": {
        "objects": {
            "location": "gs://my_bucket/",
            "paths": [
                "web-app/build/**"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm hoping for is that Google Cloud Build will recurse through the contents of the `build/` folder and copy the files & directories to my storage bucket. Instead it only copies the files that are rooted in the `build/` directory, ignores the directories and gives a warning about using the `-r` option of `gsutil cp`.

Here is the build output:

```
...
Artifacts will be uploaded to gs://my_bucket using gsutil cp
web-app/build/**: Uploading path....
Omitting directory "file://web-app/build/fonts". (Did you mean to do cp -r?)
Omitting directory "file://web-app/build/static". (Did you mean to do cp -r?)
Copying file://web-app/build/index.html [Content-Type=text/html]...
Copying file://web-app/build/asset-manifest.json [Content-Type=application/json]...
Copying file://web-app/build/favicon.ico [Content-Type=image/vnd.microsoft.icon]...
Copying file://web-app/build/manifest.json [Content-Type=application/json]...   
Copying file://web-app/build/service-worker.js [Content-Type=application/javascript]...
/ [5/5 files][ 28.4 KiB/ 28.4 KiB] 100% Done                                    
Operation completed over 5 objects/28.4 KiB.                                     
web-app/build/**: 5 matching files uploaded
5 total artifacts uploaded to gs://my_bucket/
Uploading manifest artifacts-d4a2b3e4-97ba-4eb0-b226-e0c914ac4f61.json
Artifact manifest located at gs://my_bucket/artifacts-d4a2b3e4-97ba-4eb0-b226-e0c914ac4f61.json
DONE
```

The documentation https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames#directory-by-directory-vs-recursive-wildcards suggests that this shouldn't be the case.

I guess I could use the [gsutil cloud builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/gsutil) but my suspicion is that I don't need to and that I'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's currently (2018-11) no way to copy an artifacts directory recursively one-to-one. Your best bet is to use a gsutil step in your cloudbuild.yaml file (as you mentioned already), similar to:

```
steps:
- ....
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
  args: ['-m', 'cp', '-r', 'web-app/build*', 'gs://my_bucket/$BUILD_ID']
```

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing, and it worked as expected.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208964002 -- Be sure to upvote this!

Answer (score 1):

In the end of 2022 [gcloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/storage) was released and is a lot faster to copy files than gsutils according to the [official blogpost](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/new-gcloud-storage-cli-for-your-data-transfers).

```
steps:
- ....
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud-slim"
  args: [
    "storage",
    "cp",
    "--recursive",
    "build",
    "gs://my_bucket/$BUILD_ID",
  ]
```